# Laravel Router Not Allowing Javascript Files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm having a really crazy issue and I can't seem to figure it out. I've got an app that was working perfectly fine in Laravel 5.2, and I've since upgraded to Laravel 5.3. When I serve the standard view from routes/web.php and include a script tag, Laravel is trying to load the script tag as a route instead of including the file. Example:

If I add the folowing:

```
    <script src="/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

At the end of my welcome.blade.php (or index, or any of them really), I get the following in the console:

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dzEh.png)

And if I look into Sources in the Chrome devtools at the jquery file, it's loaded my same blade file as the JS file (like Laravel is trying to load it via the router). Does anyone have any hints on where I can look? I really don't want to go through the process of trying to reinstall or back out the an earlier version.

EDIT: To clarify, I've been working on this a bit, and it turns out that the app.js file will load just fine, but the js/lib/**.js files won't. I don't really know what the difference is.

Comment: re download jquery and attack to project . and use asset()

Comment: Yeah, I have jquery locally; I've tried URL::asset, tried asset, tried bare... it all gives me the same results.

Comment: Remove Url:: just use asset .. [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset)

Answer (score 0):

How about that syntax?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('/js/lib/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Yeah, that gives me the same results as `<script src="/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

That only happens when the file is not found. Check the file name again, the path and also remember pathname may be case sensitive.